# Create different tables from 1 source table using Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a sourcetable, from which I want to create different tables, using dynamic SQL.

Sourcetable:

```
ACCP_AcceptantID    TransactionID   Descrption  Period   AcceptantNumber
1                   12              A           201801   16
1                   13              AA          201801   16
2                   21              B           201801   22
2                   46              BB          201801   22
3                   31              C           201801   54
3                   38              CC          201801   54
4                   94              D           201801   62
4                   96              DD          201801   62
```

To be able to use a WHILE Loop to select each acceptant, I created a Table Acceptants:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ACCP_AcceptantNr
INTO Acceptants
FROM Sourcetable
ALTER TABLE #TussentabelAcceptanten ADD ID INT IDENTITY

ACCP_AcceptantNr ID
16               1
22               2
54               3
62               4
```

Desired Result (for each acceptantID, own table with content):

```
ACCP_AcceptantID    TransactionID   Descrption  Period   AcceptantNumber
1                   12              A           201801   16
1                   13              AA          201801   16
```

My query attempt:

```
   DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),  
   @Acceptant NVARCHAR(40),
   @Row INT = 1

WHILE @Row <= ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Acceptants)

BEGIN

SELECT @Acceptant = ACCP_AcceptantNr FROM Acceptants

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * 
INTO MyDatabase.dbo.'+ Period + @Acceptant'
FROM #SourceTable 
WHERE ACCP_AcceptantNr = '+ @Acceptant''

EXEC (@SQL)

SET @Row = @Row + 1
SET @SQL = ''

END
```

Error message: Incorrect syntax near '

Dynamic SQL always gets the better of me. I just don't get where to place the quotes. Suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please read my question. It includes the desired result.

Comment: You want to insert data into table `MyDatabase.dbo.Period`, right? Or this `Period` is something else? Also `+ @Acceptant'` change to `+ `@Acceptant +' ` and `+ @Acceptant''` to `+ @Acceptant + '`.

Comment: At a glance, couple of errors I can see. On one line, you don't have enough `+`'s (should be `dbo.'+ Period + @Acceptant +'`). Also, at the end, you have `= '+ @Acceptant''`. you don't need any single quotes at the end (or you should have `+ ';';` (use of a terminator, as lack of it is deprecated)). Also, `Period` is completely undefined in your SQL, Not sure where that is coming from.

Comment: The table format I want to create is MyDatabase.dbo.20180116 (Note that 16 is the AcceptantNr here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the + symbols

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * 
INTO MyDatabase.dbo.'+ Period + @Acceptant+'--Added +
FROM #SourceTable 
WHERE ACCP_AcceptantNr = '+ @Acceptant -- Removed ''
```

Since you are Giving `Period` without an @ symbol, I assume it is a column from some table, so add a selet from that table otherwise this will throw an error.

Like this

```
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * 
    INTO MyDatabase.dbo.'+ Period + @Acceptant+'--Added +
    FROM #SourceTable 
    WHERE ACCP_AcceptantNr = '+ @Acceptant -- Removed ''
FROM YourTableName
```

Comment: On it's own, that isn't going to work. As I mentioned in my comments above `Period` is not defined.

Comment: @Larnu I've just added some more details to the answer

Comment: Works better. :) It likely needs a `WHERE` in there and possibly a `TOP 1`, however, the logic is unclear from the OP's current post. Ideally we need an example where the data includes different values for `Period`. At the moment you'll use whatever the last row has for a value of `Period` (and I imagine the OP has more that 6 rows in their own data). And, without an `ORDER BY` that could be anything.

Comment: Period is indeed a column in the source table.

Comment: @SQL_M I think you missed the points of my comments. Jayasurya Satheesh correctly guessed where `Period` was coming from, but we have no logic as to work out what the value of `Period` should be. You have multiple rows in your table at the moment, so Jayasurya needs to know how to determine the value of `Period` correctly for their solution to be complete.

Comment: Ok, I see, sorry. I only include laste period in source table. So in reality, it's nothing more than LEFT( CONVERT (VARCHAR, GETDATE() - 15, 112), 6).

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help, I accepted the answer!